# Mapping through mybatis

Tags: java, xml, mapping, mybatis

I do mapping through mybatis.
And I get the following error:

```
The content of element type "resultMap" must match "(constructor ?, id *, result *, association *, collection *, discriminator?)"
```

Here is the contents of mapper.xml:

```
<resultMap id="qMap" type="*.*.*.*.*.model.Q" >
    <result column="t" property="t"/>
    <result column="v" property="v"/>
    <result column="u" property="u"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="itemsMap" type="*.*.*.*.*.model.Items">
    <result column="eName" property="eName"/>
    <result column="msM" property="msM"/>
    <result column="msMem" property="msMem"/>
    <result column="dTime" property="dTime"/>
    <result column="comm" property="comm"/>
    <result column="r" property="r"/>
    <result column="st" property="st"/>
    <collection property="q" javaType="*.*.*.*.*.model.Q" resultMap="qMap"/>
    <result column="co" property="co"/>
    <result column="ch" property="ch"/>
</resultMap>
```

Error indicates at the last line. Google did not help.
What ideas or suggestions are there for correcting such a mistake? 
I'm sorry that I'm not uploading the full mapper.xml file, I also hidden the path to the model and do not post the code, because I can not show the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple XML error.  Move `<collection...` after the last `<result...`.

Comment: After move tag <collection> after the last tag <result>, I added parametr ofType in tag <collection>, and it worked. Thank you.